# http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/authorize returning invalid_client

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

When calling http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/authorize I recieve:

{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}

I am trying to make oauth2 but no matter which tutorial/docs I follow it ends up here where when I try to authorize I recieve invalid_client

But when I call http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/clients I recieve 1 client which ist the one I created in first place and I do indeed use correct ID's and all of that.

[image: Postman image]

Comment: The redirect_uri seems to be wrong, it must be the same as the client redirect_uri in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lessmore is right in his comment the URI requires to be the same as it is in the db I did not think that something like that would have to do somethin with auth. Nice! Thank you!